# Responsive web design: percentages / html5 boilerplate / 960gs or Foundation framework?

Tags: responsive-design, fluid-layout, 960.gs, html5boilerplate, zurb-foundation

I have experience in building static websites by using HTML5 and CSS3 with fixed dimensions expressed in px. I use to write CSS by hand and probably that is the best way (combined with the use of SASS and Compass wich i still have to learn). Now i have to realize a new website and i'm trying to make a flexible layout that is displayed nicely on any main browser (Internet Explorer, Firefox, Opera, Safari) with any browser size on desktop and mobile. I'm more concerned about the desktop resolution right now but if it looks good also on mobile devices it is better.

I'm currently reading the book "Responsive Web Design" by Ethan Marcotte and i'm learning about the use of percentages when i have to set a dimension by using his formula: Target / Context = Result (basically a proportion between the content and the container). I think this is a good way to make flexible websites. Responsive websites as Ethan Marcotte states should have 3 ingredients:

1. a flexible grid-based layout;
2. flexible images and media;
3. media queries.

I think it is a good way to achieve it.

---

- Apart from that theory and handcrafted CSS, there may be elements displayed differently in different browsers. I already tried Css reset and Normalize.css which i'm currently using and i prefer. I would like to try HTML5 Boilerplate which integrates also Modernizr. Do you recommend it?
- Lately there is an increasing number of grid systems (even Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 implements a way of creating fluid layout grids using also respond.js . Any good?) i'm thinking of trying 960 grid system or Foundation from ZURB. I know there is a different version of 960gs for fluid layouts, anyway is Foundation better for now for fluid layouts?
- And finally is it possible to combine HTML5 Boilerplate with 960gs or Foundation and does it make sense?

I already read questions and answers related to these topics but usually they are specific to 1 thing. I would like to have a global view of all these things together and have recommendations on how to proceed. I thank you all in advance.

Comment: why would you want to combine any of these, when they all practically target same issue? By the way, ave you looked at Bootstrap by the guys at Twitter?

Comment: hmm..they may target the same issue but they complement each other. For example Html5 Boilerplate contains not only css but also javascript libraries that are used to at least partially provide a better compatibility for older browsers. I like to use many modern css3 features that unfortunately aren't supported by older or even relatively recent browsers like internet explorer 8,9, even 10.. @IGwe

Comment: I know about Bootstrap and i heard it's also good for mobile and i still have to try it, anyway it is best if i use their features for the UI. So am i more limited about the web design if i use Bootstrap? I wouldn't like to "copy" their graphics as it may result in a website not very original. @IGwe

Comment: It's completely customizable. You don't have to copy anything at all. It's rich and featureful. It also supports IE as much as it could. There's no CSS framework that I know which solves all the quirks of IE. It's up to you as a developer to add in your own bit of plumbing work when necessary. Bootstrap is really whole and very useful, give it a go. Moreover it has a wider following currently than the rest.

Comment: I have to say this clearly - no need mentioning 960gs even - Bootstrap and Foundation both have that whole as part of their many features.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm also reading about a comparison between Bootstrap and Foundation here: http://designshack.net/articles/css/framework-fight-zurb-foundation-vs-twitter-bootstrap/ . You could consider about wrapping up your comments in an answer. I may rate it. @IGwe

Comment: I already did give an answer below. I really think you should start trying one out. Plan a simple project, and implement it repeatedly with the different frameworks. You'll definitely have an answer you can be confident in after that. That was how I came to settle with Bootstrap. Because Bootstrap is so popular, it also has an extension in the current best PHP framework - Yii.

Comment: Thanks @IGwe for your suggestions. I appreciate them. Also the extension for Yii is a plus. I'll give it a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever 960gs gives, Bootstrap and Foundation both give + more. That is Bootstrap and Foundation both already contain a grid-based layout with an option for responsiveness.

That said, I suggest you have a very close look at Bootstrap and Foundation and then draw your own comparison. Choose the one that offers the features you like more. One out of the two should be enough, if you're well organised in what you're doing.

Since you haven't even tried any, I suggest you really do now and your question will be gone in a twinkle of an eye. And I suggest you start with Bootstrap, cos when you do, you might never consider trying out the rest even.

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver CS6 provides a lot of tools for creating flexible and fluid layouts. I recommend you to use 960 grid system, and also DW provides a tool for previewing your webpage in different screen sizes (you can find this in the status bar of the webpage, in the bottom-right corner)

I am almost sure that this will help you:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/applications/getting-started-with-dreamweaver-cs6-fluid-grids/

Comment: Thanks. I already saw that tutorial on webdesign.tutplus.com and it may be useful, i'm gonna read it again and try. Anyway is the 960 grid system better? Probably yes. And i made basically 3 questions marked by an unordered list. I would like answers to all the questions. @victor

Comment: I am not sure about your other two questions. But please, if this helped you, don't forget to upvote my answer.

Comment: Yes, i won't forget. I'm waiting for other answers in the meanwhile.

Comment: About HTML5 Boillerplate: I would recommend it to you just if do not have the necessary time to make your own templates, basically because when you write your own template, you have full control of it.

Comment: Yes i think you are right about this. HTML Boilerplate may provide resources like CSS files or JS libraries filled with many items and i may probably need only a few of them, anyway they could be particularly useful in providing compatibility with older browsers, especially Internet Explorer because they are the product of the work of many good webdesigners and developers. (I like to use many modern features that unfortunately aren't supported by all the the browsers). @Victor

Comment: @Fabio, please accept the answer that helps you most, by clicking the tick under the upvote button.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Foundation by Zurb for all my latest projects; it offers everything I need. With notebook and desktop screens getting higher resolutions all the time I find that grids limited to 960 pixels are also a thing of the past, since on a large screen they only cover 50% (or less = that's like using a 480px layout on a 1024px screen)! With Foundation you can go easily wider if you adjust your font sizes accordingly. I usually go up to 1440 by now.

Comment: I didn't use Foundation by Zurb yet but i'm considering of trying it. I agree with you that grids larger that 960 pixels are better considering the dimension of today's screens. As i said to the other person who answered my question before, if you can, elaborate also on the possible integration with html5 boilerplate if possible. Feasibility and convenience or not. @j-klein

Comment: sorry, I've never used the HTML boilerplate